# HTML Jump Pages (making the section jumped to move to the top of the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a webpage and was having issues with "jumping".  Right now I have a button and when clicked it will jump to a specific section in my webpage.  However, the section jumped to remains at the bottom of the page and I would like it to move to the top.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <section class="low_arrow">
        <a href="#about" style="text-decoration: none; color = "black>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down" aria-hidden="true" id="icon_2"></i></a>
    </section>

  </div>


<!----------------- About Me ------------------->
  <div class="container_about">

      <section class="about_me" id="me">
          <h3><a name=about> ABOUT ME</a></h3> 
          <p> THIS IS ABOUT ME</p>

     </section>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code, atleast what you have tried till now.

Comment: It is going to jump to wherever your anchor is.  Move the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace below section?

```
<section class="about_me" id="about">
   <h3><a name=about> ABOUT ME</a></h3> 
   <p> THIS IS ABOUT ME</p>
</section>
```

you must check section id `<section id="about">` and `<a>` tag redirection are same `<a href="#about">` as section id.